# Who poisoned Oliver's dog in “Only Murders in the Building?”

Tags: mystery, crime, only-murders-in-the-building

In the first season of mystery drama series **Only Murders in the building**, 3 amateur crime podcasters investigate on the murder of a tenant in their building. At the end of episode 3, one of the podcasters; Oliver finds a threatening note ("*End the podcast or I end you*") pinned onto his apartment door. When he opens the door afterwards, he finds his pet dog, Winnie lying on the floor, poisoned by someone.

The initial suspect is the musical superstar Sting, who then declares he's innocent and has nothing to do with that. The killer of the tenant is eventually revealed to be

> Jan

but they themselves receives a threatening note and their handwriting does not match the one in the notes.

In season 2, this was again referenced, with Amy Schumer asking Oliver about the poisoning

> Oh, and that must make you Winnie.
> ( Winnie panting )
> Oh.
> ( baby
> talk ) Did we ever find out who poisoned you?

[Script for Season 2 Episode 1](https://tvshowtranscripts.ourboard.org/viewtopic.php?f=1038&t=54654)

and Oliver is clearly left dumbfounded, which implies he doesn't know who poisoned Winnie.

Has there been any hints on who poisoned the dog?

Comment: It was left unsolved intentionally https://www.cheatsheet.com/entertainment/only-murders-in-the-building-fans-shouldnt-forget-winnie-poisoned.html/